# Uploading a file to nodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

Client code:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append(fileName, blob, 'test.html');

fetch('http://localhost:3000/', { 
method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    },
    body: data 
}).then(
    response => {
        console.log(response)
    }
).then(
    success => {
        console.log(success)
    }
).catch(
    error =>  {
        console.log(error)
    }
);
```

Server code:

```
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log(body);
  res.send(`You sent: ${body} to Express`);
});
```

I am sending a blob in the body of a post request. When I send it to the server I want the server to download the file from the body of the request. How can i download this file? Or is there a simpler way to upload from client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my answer - https://attacomsian.com/blog/uploading-files-nodejs-express, which basically uses a middleware to do the upload.

This was basically like:

```
const x = 6;
console.log(x);
Error: value is f'd up

const x = 6;
magic.valueParse(x);
console.log(x);
6
```

Also, i would like to point out how bodyParser cannot be used for multipart data. It is mentioned on the official docs, but even responses I get seem to point to bodyParser. So I thought I'd re-iterate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can utilize an NPM package `formidable`, there appears to be a solution at: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp

Once you have the file received, you can use the `fs` module to save and store in server

Answer (score 0):

May it can solve your problem.

```
const fs = require('fs');
let directory = '/temp/data'; // where you want to save data file

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
 const body = req.body;
 console.log(body);
 fs.writeFile(directory, body, function(err) {
  if(err) {
   return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("File has been saved");
 });
 res.send(`You sent: ${body} to Express`);
});
```

Comment: If i want to add the directory like you did (/tmp/data), would it be relative to the /bin/www file?I added /tmp assuming that. The server seemed to detect the directory, but then i got this: { Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/temp' errno: -30, code: 'EROFS', syscall: 'open', path: '/temp' }. Or should I add it to the plublic folder? But I dont want this file to be public.

Comment: i first added the directory without restarting the app and got a "no directory error". when i restarted the app, i am getting a "readonly filesystem" error.

Comment: Just go to the properties of your application folder and set read write permission for your current user.

Comment: Check your root folder by console.log(process.cwd()). then set the directory.